# Sum IIf in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

```
=sum(iif(position="driver" and "labour" and "civil enginner" and "project manager" and "manager",1,0))
```

This submission is false.
What is the true submission?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

```
=Sum(Abs([position]="driver" Or [position]="labour" Or [position]="civil engineer" Or [position]="project manager" Or [position]="manager"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses , but your submission is false also, i need  total for every position in finally is separated not total for No of.positions.

Comment: I don't understand at all. Could you rephrase that please?